# Is it possible to use row access locking when using SCRIPT command in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to process the data in the table using an external script (Linux binary) with the SCRIPT_COMMAND function. However I cannot make it work so that row access lock is applied.
By default read lock seems to be applied for the whole table.

This is an example - the script command is not important.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM SCRIPT
( ON (SELECT * from user1.test_table)   
SCRIPT_COMMAND('echo test') RETURNS('text VARCHAR(30)'));
```

This returns

```
 Explanation                                                              
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
   1) First, we lock user1.test_table in TD_MAP1 for read on a     
      reserved RowHash to prevent global deadlock.                       
   2) Next, we lock user1.test_table in TD_MAP1 for read.          
(...)
```

I tried the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM SCRIPT
( ON (LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT * from user1.test_table)   
SCRIPT_COMMAND('echo test') RETURNS('text VARCHAR(30)'));
```

But it is invalid.

Comment: You can't use a LOCK modifier inside the source query. Did you try putting the modifier prior to the outer SELECT? You won't get RowHash level locks in any case for that SELECT (no WHERE clause that identifies specific PI) but you may be able to downgrade the table lock to ACCESS.

Comment: @Fred Thanks, it looks like it helps, the EXPLAIN command shows the table is getting locked with the ACCESS lock. I was pretty sure that LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS would have effect only for the immediate SELECT statement and not the nested ones.